# How can I show bullets only between two list items, instead of before each list item?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to cater for line breaks in a list so that the bullet points are used more like separators instead, I have this so far...

```css
ul {
    margin:auto;
    max-width:280px;
    list-style:none;
    text-align:center;
}
li::before {
    content: "•"; 
    color: red;
}
li {
    display:inline;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
    <li>Item 4</li>
    <li>Item 5</li>
    <li>Item 6</li>
    <li>Item 7</li>
    <li>Item 8</li>
</ul>
```

How can I make sure that list items aren't split between lines and also make sure that bullet points only display if it isn't a new line?

I am try to make things look like this...

[image]

The width of the container and the number of items does change so trying to do this without assigning individual classes

Comment: Basically... **you can't**.

Comment: To elaborate on Paulie's comment, you would need JavaScript to detect the positioning of each one, *or* you would need to know the exact width of each item (in addition to the width of the container and the number of items) and use `nth-child` selectors (or add classes to each one, but you said you don't want to do that).

Comment: What is about this: https://jsfiddle.net/tkjrhm5g/ ?

Comment: @mr.void This does not remove the bullet from the 1st item on the second row. **You can't do this with CSS**.

Comment: Oh then i misunderstood, sorry

Answer (score -1):

A couple of techniques will help you achieve this effect.
1st use first-child on the list element to hide the first separator.

The second is a little hacky but it's the way to hide the bullet when the menu rows wrap; Use a pseudo-element on the ul to create an overlay to hide the first bullet in the second row.

If you want to align the bottom row to the middle you're going to want to use flexbox, with justify-content:center and move your bullet to the right after each element. Move the ul overlay to the right and hide the bullet of the last-child instead of the first-child.

```css
ul{margin:auto;max-width:300px;list-style:none;text-align:center; position:relative; overflow:hidden;padding-left:0; display:flex; flex-wrap:wrap; justify-content: center; }
ul:before {content:" "; height: 100%; position:absolute; right:0; width:0.75rem; background-color: #fff; z-index:2; }
ul> li{display:inline; padding:0 0.5rem; position:relative;}
ul > li:before {position:absolute; right:0; transform:translateX(50%); content: "•"; color: red;}
ul > li:last-child:before{ display:none;}
```

```html
<ul>
<li>Item 1</li>
<li>Item 2</li>
<li>Item 3</li>
<li>Item 4</li>
<li>Item 5</li>
<li>Item 6</li>
<li>Item 7</li>
<li>Item 8</li>
</ul>
```